# Hadoop Pig Max - Not correct output

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am having some trouble with an apparently simple PIG MAX function which does not work for me.
I did a grouping where I calculated a sum.

```
C3 = FOREACH C2 GENERATE group, SUM(C1.figures);
```

I receive the following output

```
(Peter, 345)
(Paul, 459)
(Andi, 500)
```

Now I want to get the max value so that the output is

```
(Andi, 500)
```

I am trying the following code

```
 C4 = FOREACH C3 GENERATE $0 as (id: chararray), $1 as (id2:long);
 C5 = GROUP C4 ALL;
 C6 = FOREACH C5 GENERATE C4.id, MAX(C4.id2);
```

But as output I am getting

```
 ({Peter, Paul, Andi}, 500)
```

which is not what I wanted.

Can anybody help? Would be much appreciated

cheers,
Andi

Answer (score 1):

Solved it via 
   sort = ORDER C4 by id2 DESC;
   limit = LIMIT sort 1;